# If else in oracle SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a scenario where I can get 2 types of inputs but the outcome is same if you include input 1 or input 2 or both. The following is the query which I have currently. This query retrieves the `customer_id` from the database from the `circuit` and `telephone` inputs.

```
select customer.customer_id from circuits join customer on customer.cust_order = circuits.cust_order where circuitId= 'somecircuit'
union
select customer.customer_id from customer join telephone on telephone.number = customer.number where telephone = '34234242'
```

Now I need the second query to not execute if the input telephone is not available and vice versa for the circuit. Is there a way to do this in the query itself?

I'm not planning on creating a PL/SQL block for this, If there is no way to do it in the sql i have to resort to Java and two different queries for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
select customer.customer_id
from circuits join customer on customer.cust_order = circuits.cust_order
where circuitId is not null
union
select customer.customer_id
from customer join telephone on telephone.number = customer.number
where telephone is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

You can join all your tables in the SQL query and let the WHERE condition handle the rest:

SELECT customer.customer_id 
FROM circuits JOIN customer ON customer.cust_order = circuits.cust_order 
JOIN telephone on telephone.number = customer.number 
WHERE circuitId= 'somecircuit' OR telephone = '34234242'

Either the circuit id that is set will retrieve your customer's data or the telephone number.

Comment: If the circuitId is empty, wouldn't it fail? I'll be sending empty string if the circuit input is empty and the circuit table will match with nothing and the join conditions would result in empty results.

Comment: No, even if the circuitId is not given, the OR operator will help us fetch records using the telephone number.